# best way to transfer tables from SQL Server to Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis

I recently moved a SQL Server 2012 database from an old web server to Azure SQL.  I also keep a copy of the database on my personal machine which is now running SQL Server 2019.  During development, I frequently make changes to tables on my local machine and then need to transfer those tables to the server.  I used to do this using a Visual Studio SSIS package.  It was very easy.  I used the "Transfer SQL Server Objects" task to select one or more tables, specify whether the existing tables should be dropped first, and replaced the tables on the server.  The "Transfer SQL Server Objects" task does not work when trying to transfer objects to Azure SQL because it uses the "USE" statement.  There must be an easy way to transfer tables to an Azure SQL database.  I've used the "Microsoft Data Migration Assistant" and it works great for the initial migration, but does not allow you to replace tables.  I feel like I am missing something very obvious because transferring tables is a routine task and there must be an easy way to do this with Azure SQL.

Comment: The workflow feels wrong here. Why you you consistently dropping your tables in Azure and remaking them in the first place? If you're dropping them, the data goes too. Something feels wrong here.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm totally off-base, as I've never used Azure, but surely you can run DDL on the Azure DB as a DBA? If so, you should be scripting out your changes that you make on your development DB and apply those changes via script to the Azure DB. It would be no different than a local dev SQL Server and a local production SQL Server.

Comment: Could you use database projects to manage the schema and then use SSIS to move the data.  With db projects you can manage both your local schema and the Azure db.  Using `Publish` you can detect and apply changes.  This would also set you up to source control your schema so you can get back to a previous state

Comment: Are you transferring DDL (table changes), data, or both? I highly recommend a database project to manage DDL changes

Answer (score 1):

Manually managing and synchronizing different database versions can be time-consuming. The Schema Compare addon facilitates database comparison and provides you complete control when syncing them — you may filter particular differences and categories of differences before making modifications. The Schema Compare addon is a trustworthy tool that will save you time and code.

> Hence, the Schema Compare extension provides an easy-to-use experience
> to compare two database definitions and apply the differences from the
> source to the target. MSFT Ddocument which could be usefull : Schema
> Compare extension- [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-use-schema-compare-to-compare-different-database-definitions?view=sql-server-ver15) and How to: Use Schema Compare to Compare
> Different Database Definitions - [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/extensions/schema-compare-extension?view=sql-server-ver15).